# sum-digits function - C language

Tags: c, sum, digits

Digits Sum  function 
I have to write a function - digits sum,
for ex.:  the number : 9887, 9+8+8+7= 32 , 3+2= 5
Will this function work well?

```
int sum_digits(int num){
    if (num < 10)
       return num;
    int a = sum_digits (num / 10) + num % 10;
    if (a > 9)
        a = sum_digits (a / 10) + a % 10;
       return a;
}
```

Comment: Not sure.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Well ... if your function says the sum of digits of 9887 is 4, your function is wrong.

Comment: Probably not. What happens if the last computed sum (the second time `a`) is above 9?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a crowdsourced compiler.  Try it yourself.

Comment: I think OP is indirectly asking: "please explain to me why it doesn't work". But here we like direct questions...

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum_digits(int num){
    if (num < 10)
       return num;
    int a = sum_digits (num / 10) + num % 10;
    if (a > 10)
        a += sum_digits (a / 10) + a % 10;
       return a;
}
```

This will work.

Note that a= is replaced by a+= and a>9 is replaced by a>10

Comment: for all who answered not kindly:

Comment: this function is working!!! i just want to know if anyone can prove why. if i senf 9887 this function goes to 7 , comes back to 8 and makes 7+8=15=1+5=6,    then goes back to 8 (hundred digit) and makes 6+8=14=1+4=5   and to 9- 9+5= 1+4= 5 .                                             when i calculate i do 9+8+8+7=32   3+2=5      .    And because i do it in another way i want to know if it aill always work!!!!!!!! I cant try all the numbers in the worls....:)